# Use Existing database with SQLCipher

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, sqlcipher

Is it possible to open an existing SQLite database with SQLCipher?

Until now, I was managed only to create a new database using SQLCipher in order to work with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open an existing SQLite database, go through the documentation : http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/

Comment: Hi Sharon, can you explain the steps to me?
say I have an existing database which is unencrypted. then what?

Comment: To encrypt a database programatically you can use the sqlite3_key function. 
The data provided in pKey is converted to an encryption key according to the 
same rules as PRAGMA key. 


  int sqlite3_key(sqlite3 *db, const void *pKey, int nKey);

PRAGMA key or sqlite3_key should be called as the first operation when a database is open.

Comment: To encrypt a plaintext database, you will want to use the sqlcipher_export function, specifically look at example 1: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export